# C++:pthread status monitoring on Linux

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have an application running 8 independent threads, generated through a Wrapper Class around Pthread. All threads are running in infinite while loop, with a cycle time of 1 second each. From the main thread (Main Function, also running in infinite while loop)  , i want to monitor the thread status whether the thread has got blocked for some reason or not. Is there any way of doing it through system calls for monitoring thread status?

Comment: You could call ps from main thread and look at status of the individual threads, for example if the thread sits in S+ or D state. Or look at ps src code and do it directly without invoking ps and parsing its output.

Answer (score 0):

GDB is the best option ,

attach gdb to the running process using the below command

```
gdb -p "pid"

info threads
```

this will display all the threads in the application and status of each thread

Comment: I want to do it in the Program itself, gdb is not an option...Have got some decision making to do based on Thread status

Answer (score 0):

You can access process status information in the proc filesystem. Using the PIDs of the threads, you can look up their status in `/proc/[PID]/status`

The contents of the status file looks like:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-159:/proc/1151$ cat status
Name:   systemd-logind
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   1151
Ngid:   0
Pid:    1151
PPid:   1
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    0   0   0   0
Gid:    0   0   0   0
...
```